# Django: How to re-route a request to a different view using middleware

Tags: django, routes, middleware

I'm trying to work with the following scenario:

When a GET request comes in to my "/" route I normally want to handle it with my HomeView. However, my site is heavy AJAX so if the request's UserAgent is a bot then I serve it up with a fully rendered version of the page (standard PhantomJS stuff). The approach works fine, but the performance of the fully rendered version, and the SLA for that version, is very different than the regular user view. As such, I would like to use a piece of middleware to do the bot detection and based on that middleware I would then like to send the request to a different View.

The middleware part is easy, I have a process_request handler that detects the bot - no big deal. However, I can't figure any option for overriding the View function that will be invoked. Is there a "proper" way to do this in Django? My current thoughts are:

- modify request.path_info to change the requested URL so that the router will then send HtmlRendererView rather than HomeView
- Call the HtmlRendererView directly from the middleware and return the appropriate HttpResponse. This feels clunky because it then takes away the opportunity for any other middleware to run.

Notes:

- I don't want to return a redirect, the crawler is getting a different version of the *same* resource
- I'm on heroku so I can't rewrite the route before it hits Django. If I was using nginx I'd probably just put this logic at that layer and rewrite the URL before it hit Django.

Comment: Update: Altering path_info did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question ("Reroute a request to a different view"), but maybe this solution could adress your problem.

First, you keep your middleware, but use it only to detect if the visitor is a bot:

```
def process_request(self, request):     
    request.is_bot = is_bot(request) # assuming you have a function for detecting bots
    return
```

Then you create a class based view that call a specific method when `request.is_bot` is True:

```
class BotViewMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, **kwargs):

        if request.is_bot:
            return self.handle_bot()
        return super(BotViewMixin, self).dispatch(request, **kwargs)
```

You can then inherit this view anywhere you need (e.g. for your Home Page View). You just have to create a `handle_bot` method on your view, that will return your response for bots.

Advantages of this solution:

- You don't need to write different views for bots, just create a dedicated method
- You don't block other middlewares
- Your logic stay in your views (and not in your middleware)

This is not tested though, so you may need to adapt the code.

EDIT:

Since you use NewRelic and must use a dedicated view for bots in order to get accurate statistics, this approach won't work for you.

You can go with the middleware thing, and still get all middlewares working. You just have to put your own middleware last in MIDDLWARE_CLASSES:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'yourproject.CrawlerDetector',
)
```

Also, I think you should write two middlewares methods: `process_request` for detecting bots, and [`process_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) for redirecting bots to dedicated view.

The following code should probably work for your situation:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
class CrawlerDetector(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        """detect if the user agent is a bot"""
        user_agent = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', "")
        request.is_bot = self.is_crawler(user_agent)
        return

    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if request.is_bot and request.path == reverse('home_page'):
            return HtmlRendererView().get(request)
        return
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @EliotBerriot.
 
I think the only problem with the approach you've outlined is that my primary motivation for making this change is so that NewRelic will provide accurate statistics of my BotView vs my HomeView. So I'm somewhat limited in my design flexibility. If I used the dispatch method, then I believe Django will have already selected my View and NewRelic will attribute the call to that view.

Comment: Okay, so you have to return another view for your bot. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

My current working solution, while not as clean as Eliot's suggested solution, looks (basically) like this:

```
class CrawlerDetector(object):

    # Middleware that detects requests that should be rendered by the HtmlRendererView.
    def process_request(self, request):
        user_agent = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', "")
        if not self.is_crawler(user_agent):
            return None
        return HtmlRendererView().get(request)
```

It has the downside of removing any downstream middleware from the flow, but it does allow me to call my crawler-specific View before the root View is routed to.